# Can you create a symlink for a file to multiple targets in bash?

Tags: bash, symbolic-link, symlink

I am looking to create a symlink for a file (E.g., `/var/log/cron/cron.log`) which will have a symlink to both `/proc/1/fd/2` and `/proc/1/fd/1`.

Is this possible?

Comment: How should this work? Maybe you want just to redirect **stdout** and **stderr** to the same file?

Comment: If something is written to `cron.log`, it would be written to both `/proc/1/fd/1` and /proc/1/fd/2` which doesn't seem to be possible according to the answer below.

Comment: `/proc/1/fd/1` and `/proc/1/fd/2` are the standard output and standard error descriptors of the **init** process. You can not write to them anyway. Maybe it is the other way around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it can only point to one target. Since a link points to a specific inode on the target, only one can exist at a time

Comment: Figured that'd be the case. Was worth asking.

Comment: Never hurts to ask

Answer (score 0):

[Kevin](https://serverfault.com/a/999853/530633) already answered to the letter of the question, I'll try to answer to the spirit. If you want to write to two files at the same time (assuming one of the is not a hard/symbolic link to the other), you can use **named pipes** and the `tee` command to duplicate output:

```
mkfifo dup.txt
tee -a a.txt >> b.txt < dup.txt &
echo "Hello world!" >> dup.txt
```

will get `"Hello world!"` written to both `a.txt` and `b.txt`. However **tee** will exit after the first write.

Since in your example you use a logfile, a more stable solution would be to configure [rsyslogd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/rsyslog.conf.5.html) to send all `cron` messages to multiple files:

```
cron.* -/var/log/cron/cron.log
cron.* -/var/log/another-file.log
```